# For loop in Python working, but not doing it's job

Tags: python, for-loop, parameters

I'm new to Python, i wanted to start learning it and here i try to rewrite a little code that i wrote in C# before. The program counts factorial, so if i type in 6 it would be 720. This is the python code:

```
   import array

def countFactorial(tal):
    summ = 1

    for i in range(len(tal)):
            summ *= i
            i += 1
    print("{} is".format(tal))
    print("{}".format(summ))
    return summ

def main():

    lst = []
    for i in range(5):
        values = input("Type in a value: ")
        lst.append(values)

    for s in lst:
        countFactorial(s)
       # print(s)


main()
```

If the user would type in for example 6, this is what the program for now will type out: "6 is 0" (5 times).

This is a part of the for loop that i tried to rewrite from C# that doesn't work here. Obviously "tal" is passed on as a parameter here in the C# aswell.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= tal; i++)
        {
            summ *= i;

        }
        Console.WriteLine(tal + " is " + summ);
```

What i think i need is a while loop that needs to rund the summ code trough like for example 6 times. I've tried this but cannot work it out.

Comment: In `countFactorial` you modify `i` twice, once in `for i in range...` and once in `i += 1`, the second modification is lost.

Comment: @finitegraygreen Well what i tried to create there was as you can se in the c# code(if you know c#). Like a "while loop" where i want "i" to increment untill it equals "tal"

Comment: You are also using the *length* of `tal` as the number (a string), so you are using the *number of digits* as the loop value.

Comment: So if i understood right, im using the user input to declare how many times it loops? But it will always loop 5 times anyways? @MartijnPieters

Comment: @kastravec: you are always asking for 5 numbers. Each of those entries remains a `str` object, because you never  convert the value to an `int` object. String objects are sequences and have length, the number of characters in the string (so `len('5') == 1`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ranges without an explicit starting value start at `0`, so the first time you multiply `1` by `0`. From there on out `summ` stays `0`.

Your C# code on the other hand, starts at 1 and include the end value.

Either start your Python `range()` objects at `1` too and stop at `tal + 1`:

```
summ = 1
for i in range(1, tal + 1):
    summ *= i
```

*or* add 1 to `i` when multiplying:

```
summ = 1
for i in range(tal):
    summ *= (i + 1)
```

The `i += 1` you added was redundant; `i` is set to the next value in the range on the next iteration, replacing whatever `i` was bound to before.

You do need to pass in integers; `input()` in Python 3 returns a *string*, so you need to convert it to an integer first:

```
for i in range(5):
    value = int(input("Type in a value: "))
    lst.append(value)
```

Comment: Ok now i understand the error, but how would i "make" ranges start at 1, or the "i" start at 1. do i just "i = 1" under the for loop?

Comment: Thanks man it worked! You also explained everything well so now i understand it! Thank you yet again!